# OnTouchListener animates all buttons when one button gets pressed

Tags: android, animation, android-animation, ontouchlistener

So I have 3 buttons on a custom adapter in a ListView.
Whenever I press one of the buttons, the animation gets triggered for the button I have a `OnTouchListener` for every button and the animation works as expected on `ACTION_DOWN`. But on `ACTION_UP`all three buttons animate rather than just the one I've clicked. I've put `Log.i` inside the listener and it seems to be working correctly. What else could be causing this?

Below find the code for the animations and the buttons listeners:

```
           //Animation for the buttons
            final ScaleAnimation zoom_in = new ScaleAnimation(1f, 0.9f, 1f, 0.9f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
            final ScaleAnimation zoom_out = new ScaleAnimation(0.9f, 1f, 0.9f, 1f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
            zoom_in.setFillAfter(true);
            zoom_out.setFillAfter(true);
            zoom_in.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
            zoom_out.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
            zoom_in.setDuration(200);
            zoom_out.setDuration(200);

            final Button likeButton = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.graffiti_like_button);
            likeButton.setOnTouchListener(new Button.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    switch (event.getAction()) {
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                            // start your first zoom out Animation here
                            likeButton.startAnimation(zoom_in);
                            break;

                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                            // start zoom in animation which returns to original state
                            likeButton.startAnimation(zoom_out);
                            break;
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                            // start zoom in animation which returns to original state
                            likeButton.startAnimation(zoom_out);
                            break;
                        default:
                            //v.clearAnimation();
                            break;
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            });

            final Button commentButton = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.graffiti_comment_button);
            commentButton.setOnTouchListener(new Button.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    switch (event.getAction()) {
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                            // start your first zoom out Animation here
                            commentButton.startAnimation(zoom_in);
                            break;

                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                            // start zoom in animation which returns to original state
                            commentButton.startAnimation(zoom_out);
                            break;
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                            // start zoom in animation which returns to original state
                            commentButton.startAnimation(zoom_out);
                            break;
                        default:
                            //v.clearAnimation();
                            break;
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            });

            final Button shareButton = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.graffiti_share_button);
            shareButton.setOnTouchListener(new Button.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    switch (event.getAction()) {
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                            // start your first zoom out Animation here
                            shareButton.startAnimation(zoom_in);
                            break;

                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                            // start zoom in animation which returns to original state
                            shareButton.startAnimation(zoom_out);
                            break;
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                            // start zoom in animation which returns to original state
                            shareButton.startAnimation(zoom_out);
                            break;
                        default:
                            //v.clearAnimation();
                            break;
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            });
```

Comment: add zoom_in.xml and zoom_out.xml @Aci89

Comment: Done @ChiragTalsaniya